# Draw Lines on Camera's Viewport

Tags: unity, c#, vector, editors

I wanted to know if there is a way to draw lines on the viewport, just like on the example image I am posting. My idea is to have a method that receives 2 Vector2, the origin and the end of the line, just like Gizmos.DrawLine (except that it takes Vector3 instead), that would be internally clamped to  be normalized.

[image]

```
public class DrawMeLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// Just draw the lines on editor mode, and only when selected.
    void OnGizmosDrawSelected()
    {
        DrawLineOnViewport(new Vector2(0f, 0f), new Vector2(1f, 1f));
    }

    void DrawLineOnViewport(Vector2 origin, Vector2 end)
    {
        origin.x = Mathf.Clamp(origin.x, 0f, 1f);
        origin.y = Mathf.Clamp(origin.y, 0f, 1f);
        end.x = Mathf.Clamp(end.x, 0f, 1f);
        end.y = Mathf.Clamp(end.y, 0f, 1f);

        /// Proceed to draw lines on Viewport...
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance, let me know if there is any additional information necessary for me to give.

**NOTE:** I already have a struct that has its values ranged, so the clamping wouldn't be necessary, it was written just for the sake of example.

Comment: I assume you just want a screen space line.  Which you can do, the difference being that its -1 to 1 in both X and Y.  sample would be screenspaceX  = (YourXValue * 2.0f) - 1.0f; screenspaceY = (YourYValue * -2.0f) - 1.0f;  All off the top of my head, but all you are looking to do is draw in the screenspace.  Set Your Z Value to near the closest Z Value as defined in your projection matrix to ensure its closest (Or turn off Z test).

Comment: I thought that I could do something with the camera.near, but didn't give a try. I'll see if it works.

Comment: Just remember, to set the Z not on your limit, as it may cull.